# I started coding a few days ago and I had trouble with this message "cant add script component because the script class cannot be found" (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a script in Unity (using Visual Studio Code).  Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Propellermovement : MonoBehaviour

{
    private GameObject propeller;
    public float Propellerspeed;
   
  
    void Update()
    {

    transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * Propellerspeed * Time.deltaTime);
    
    }}
```

I don't know if someone knows how to help me.

I created new scripts and it still didn't work. I can't add the component to an object, and I don't know if it is because it's an object into an object (sorry English its not my first language).

Comment: Did you rename the file from Propellermovement to something else? Or rename the class inside the file? Unity requires them to match

Comment: ^ your component class name, and the file name must match ***exactly***. In your case, your file needs to be “Propellermovement.cs”.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, your file name must **exactly** match the name of your class.  You need to have your file named **exactly** "Propellermovement.cs".  If you change the name of your class, you must also change the name of your CS file in order for Unity to properly recognize it.